# Django 1.1 localizing datetimes

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I'm using Django 1.1, and trying to localise it to other languages. One aspect of that is localizing dates/times. Django uses 'Technical message ids' ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/#django-technical-message-ids ), but I'm not sure what those are, and the documentation is lacking.

- Can I create my own date time formats? If the language is en-GB, it should show X, if it's fr, then it should show Y. For the textual content I can change that easy enough with the .po files.
- How do I change what the 'MONTH_FORMAT' for let's say, French?

Comment: So if textual content is fine (assuming youre using .po) then whats the problem? In templates you should use {% trans "" %} tags, in models ugettext_lazy and content data field is adjusted according to localization or filters.